# Synergy Setup Issue

Tags: windows-7, windows, synergy

I am currently using synergy on my 3 Windows machines. The program works great except it doesn't realize that my Serve 1 screens are 4 and not one. Here is my current monitor set up.

|-----------||-------------||-----------|

| Client 2 || Server 1 || Server 1 |

|-----------||-------------||-----------|

|-----------||-------------||-----------|

| Client 1 || Server 1 || Server 1 |

|-----------||-------------||-----------|

and here is how it appears to be when I move the mouse around with synergy running:

|-----------|

| Client 2 |

|-----------|

|-----------||-------------||-----------|

| Client 1 || Server 1 || Server 1 |

|-----------||-------------||-----------|

How would I make it so that I don't need to go through Client 1 in order to get to Client 2 machine, and can just access it straight from Server 1 to Client 2.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you speaking of this Synergy? http://www.profitstars.com/imaging-and-payments/enterprise-content-management/synergy/pages/default.aspx

If so just call 1.800.299.4222

Answer (score 0):

No

This is the program 
synergy-project.org/

I'm sure it is possible to do using the config file bnut have no idea going about it